# Fat Free Framework - Concatenating Template Strings

Tags: php, twig, concatenation, slim, fat-free-framework

I have a web app I'm porting from Slim v3 to Fat Free Framework. The logic part has been straight-forward. My problem has been converting some Twig view templates to F3 templates; specifically I'm having difficulty building concatenated strings to populate Materialize class fields.

For instance, suppose my Contact Form validation passes back a **message_err** that states, "The name field must be at least 3 characters."

The Slim app, utilizing Twig's template engine, would check to see if **data.name_err** was empty, if not it would create a new **messageName** by concatenating 'data-err="' with data.name_err and this would then be used to display an error state in a Materialize form. Here's a code snippet:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    {% if data.name_err %}
        {%  set messageName = 'data-error="'~data.name_err~'"' %}
    {% endif %}
    some more code here...
</div>
```

I've tried to do something similar using F3's built in template engine, but it throws errors with everything I've tried. Here were a few attempts:

```
<set msg="data-error=&#34 {{ @data.name_err }} "></set>
```

and:

```
<set msg="{{ data-error=&#34 @data.name_err &#34}}"></set>
```

As there seems to be no way to escape characters in strings, that's why I was trying to use ASCII codes for the quotes. I tried it with the equals sign too, but got errors nonetheless.

If anybody has any thoughts I'd be most appreciative. Otherwise I'll have to dig into changing some core logic.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
<set msg="{{ 'data-error=&#34'.@data.name_err.'&#34'}}"></set>
```

Comment: thank you for responding, but that still throws an error: `syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pt-ff3/tmp/z12j1lprjqvu.6kt2ovz0t896.php:1]` Does it work definitely on your system? Perhaps I've screwed something else up in my testing?

Comment: To be fair, I fully suspect that ikkez believed they WERE answering the question. I use several of their F3 libraries, and value their work greatly. Which is why I'm wondering if there is something else not working in my testing environment? Can anybody else confirm whether or not the snippet above works for them?

Comment: I believe there is an issue parsing the <set> tag when there are double-quotes in the expression.

Comment: yeah probably it's a bug.. I've not tested the snippet from above

Comment: I've tested and corrected my example... should be working this way

Answer (score 0):

In F3, you can use `{~ <code> ~}` to execute php expressions without echoing the result.

```
{~ @msg = "data-error=\"@data.name_err\""  ~}
```